# lineChart with Task<> in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, linechart

I am working on a **JavaFX** Project to analyze Stocks and I am using LineChart, The **lineChart** was working Perfectly, but when I start using **Task**<>, so the User would get blocked while analyzing, it got weird, The X-Axis which is the Date Period got all smushed together.

```
Task<DataModel> t1 = new Task<>() {
                @Override
                protected DataModel call() {
                    List<DataModel> = graphValues =
                            query.getData(data.getSymbol(), startDate, endDate);
                    return null;
                }
            };
    t1.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent wse) -> {
       XYChart.Series<String, Number> closeSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
                lineChart.getData().add(closeSeries);

                for (DataModel node : graphValues) {
                    XYChart.Data<String, Number> closeData =
                            new XYChart.Data<>(node.getDate(), node.getClose());

                    closeSeries.getData().add(closeData);
                }
            t1.setOnFailed((WorkerStateEvent wse) -> System.out.println("Do something"));
            Thread th = new Thread(t1);
            th.setDaemon(true);
            th.start();
```

[image]

I could not figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a bug - might be related somehow to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198830 (reported for categoryAxis but also seen in other axis types). Sometimes it helps to disable animations, another way out might be to not rely on auto-ranging

Comment: You see if a third-party library would work for you. https://github.com/GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try to work around it!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this bug was either setting the categories manually instead of letting the chart find them.

```
xAxis.setCategories(xAxisList);
```

or the more simple way:

```
xAxis.setAnimated(false)
```